# Why java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class is thrown on Deploy operation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, weblogic12c, spring-framework-beans, spring-oxm

Case 1:
When I deploy an application with Jenkins in an environment say E1, it works successfully. App gets deployed and no errors on Jenkins console output. 
Case 2:
When I deploy the same application with Jenkins in another environment say E2, the deploy operation fails but the app does get deploy in the server. Though I get errors in Jenkins console. I am confused, Is it code issue or server issue, how can I fix it? 
Below is the error in this case:

> Target state: deploy failed on Cluster xCluster
>   15:53:27 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.JaxbUtils.(JaxbUtils.java:44)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:272)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.AbstractJaxbMarshaller.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractJaxbMarshaller.java:125)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
>   15:53:27    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializer(WebAppServletContext.java:1389)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1326)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1312)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1829)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2891)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:553)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
>   15:53:27    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

Comment: There is something different in your environments, most likely the jars available on the container's classpath.

Comment: Thanks! Atleast it doesn't seem to be the code issue. 
where can I find the jars available on the container's classpath and what are required jars in it?

Comment: Weblogic ships with spring internally. Add a weblogic descriptor so that you can configure the application preferred packages. By default the server supplied version are preferred.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't know how to add a WL descriptor. Also what jars that are not present or in conflict, causing this issue?

Comment: So, there was no web-app folder in my war module. So now I have added it and below are the contents of it. 
> <wls:container-descriptor>
  <wls:prefer-application-packages>
   <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
   <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.*</wls:package-name>
   <wls:package-name>org.joda.time.*</wls:package-name>
   <wls:package-name>org.apache.logging.*</wls:package-name>
   <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
  </wls:prefer-application-packages>
 </wls:container-descriptor>
Not sure which preferred package to include for my error.

Comment: `web-app` folder? There is a `WEB-INF` or `META-INF` folder but no such thing as a `web-app` folder? The content of that file should be enough, place it in the right directory of your application.

Comment: Sorry, my bad it is WEB-INF/weblogic.xml. After having the contents as per my previous comment, on deploy I still get the same error. 
(Did I miss any preferred package name?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate the comments from Deinum and Roddy!
 I was able to resolve the issue/error and the deploy operation was successful. 
Here is what I did:
I found multiple versions of spring-oxm in my library. I had to remove the oldest one and and retained the latest one which came from spring-boot-starter-web-services kit. Once you have single version and latest version of spring-oxm jar, you should be able to build, test and deploy successfully. 
This was the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

for me :
**implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.17'**

just  remove  **implementation 'org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.17'**
it  workr for me .